# How put div element to bottom of another div element

Tags: html, css

I have two div element. I want to understand how to do the following:[image]

I have HTML and CSS:

```
    <div class="main">
      <div class="iner"></div>
    </div>
```

And

```
.main{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #111210;

}

.iner{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #34cb2f;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

This CSS code center iner block but it display on top position.
How to put the iner block to the bottom of main outer block like on the imege?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use flexbox:

```
.main {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #111210;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #34cb2f;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/yuwubutiqi/

Comment: This is probably the best solution which does not use position 'relative' & 'absolute'.

Answer (score 8):

- Set `position: relative;` to the **parent** element
- Set `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;` to the **inner** element

```css
.main{
  position:relative; /* ADD THIS! */
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #111210;
}

.iner{
  position:absolute; /* ADD THIS! */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #34cb2f;
  bottom: 0;
  /* some horizontal centering now... */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="iner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is not need for margin since it position is absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your main div's width is 500px and inner div's width is 300px

```
 .main{
        width:500px;
        height:auto:margin:auto;
        background-color:green;
        border:1px solid #000000;
        min-height:500px;position:relative
        }

.inner{
        width:300px;
        height:auto;
        min-height:300px;
        background-color:yellow;
        position:absolute;
        bottom : 0;
        margin-right:100;
        margin-left:100px"
        }
```